# ArgumentException when calling .ToArray()

Tags: c#, .net

I have a List that is cleared out every so often.  The code is exactly like this:

```
VisitorAgent[] toPersist;
List<VisitorAgent> v = (List<VisitorAgent>)state;

lock (v)
{
   toPersist = v.ToArray();                       

   v.Clear();
}

//further processing of toPersist objects
```

Today i just got an Argument exception which doesn't make sense to me unless there was a memory issue.  But if that was the case, why not OOM exception?  What could cause this exception when calling ToArray()?

```
System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and 
length, and the array's lower bounds.
```

I am using .NET 3.5 & C#.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This just screams race condition (the `lock` statement was the first clue).

I'd guess that some other code (in another thread) has added to the `List<T>` after it allocates the destination array but before it gets around to copying it.

The first thing I'd do is double-check that every possible access to your state list is properly wrapped in a `lock` statement.

Comment: Im almost positive you are right, after you said that, i went through all my refences to the state object, and it looks like i missed one.

Answer (score 0):

Something is changing the `state` list between the time the array is allocated and the time the contents of the list are copied.  Locking on `v` would have no effect on this unless the code that populates state knows about `v` (which it doesn't seem to in this example).