# Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this scheduled task that runs every day on the server, the task was working perfectly for 1 year. After a server change (moved the task to a new server), the task started crashing with this execption:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Destination array was not long enough.
Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.
at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray,
Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
at System.Collections.ArrayList.ToArray()
at Directory.MessageVector.findMessageById(Int32 msgId)
at Directory.Connection.ReaderThread.Run()
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext,  
ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

I looked on the internet for this error but all I found relateed to multithreading, parallel programming and locking mechanisms. BUT my task doesn't use any of that, it does not use parallel programming or locking mechanisms, it a simple task that retrieves data from databases and send emails and it was perfectly running before the server change.

ANY IDEAS ????
thank's.

Comment: have you checked the code line where it is occurring??

Comment: well, i can't since it s a dll i am using, i call a function in that dll, the developper of that dll, told me that nothing wrong with their code and sent me theire logs indicating that the function calls were ok.

Comment: Hashtable mgList=new Hashtable();
using(IDataReader dataReader=db.ExecuteReader(dbCommandWrapper))
{
 user=new User();
 while(dataReader.Read())
 {
  mid=dataReader["Mid"].ToString();
  if(!mgList.ContainsKey(mid))
  {
   Mgr mgr=user.getMgrInfos(mid);
   mgList.Add(mgr.id, mgr);
  }
  Mbr mbr=user.getMbrInfos(dataReader["Id"].ToString());
  if (mbr!=null)
  {
   mbr.Date=(DateTime)dataReader["Date"];
   mbr.Nbr=int.Parse(dataReader["Nbr"].ToString());
   mbr.New=dataReader["New"].ToString();
   Mgr mgr=(Mgr)mgList[mid];
   mgr.mbrList.Add(mbr);
  }
 }
}
return mgList;

Answer (score 0):

According to the stack trace `ArrayList.ToArray` is throwing the exception. Something is indeed horribly wrong. Is your app multithreaded? Does the third-party DLL support multiple threads? If it does, somebody probably forgot to properly synchronize that specific `ArrayList`. If not, you probably have to synchronize calls to the DLL.

See this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3188783/argumentexception-when-calling-toarray) for example.

Edit: I missed looking at the last couple of stack frames. Multithreading is indeed in play here.

Comment: Agree. worth checking that calls to the DLL are synchronized.

Answer (score 0):

As you rightly say most of the article online refer to multithreading issues.

The fact that your exception says

```
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

suggests that this is in fact the case. 
Might be worth searching your code for any instances of/reference to "System.Threading".
Alternatively if you are certain it's not your code ask for the DLL source code or at least a debug build so that you attach a debugger.